# error: invalid method declaration; return type required ERROR While calling a Method

Tags: java

Hi guys I am a new Computer Science student and I am trying to call a method and I keep on getting this error. Here is my problem area:

```
calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);
```

Here is the entire code(It's not too long):

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class SpeedingTicket
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    //Declarations and Instantiations
{
    // Input Data
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter driver's name: ");
    String driverName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter driver's speed: ");
    int speedDriving = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter speed limit: ");
    int speedLimit = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Was driver in school zone? ");
    String schoolZone = scan.nextLine();

}

    // Call calcTicket

    calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);

/** Calculates the cost of a speeding ticket given the speed driven, limit, and if in a school zone.

 */ 
public static void calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone)
{
    // Define constants here

    final int INIT_ADDITIVE = 50;
    final int NO_MULTIPLIER = 6;
    final int YES_MULTIPLIER = 12; 
    final int MAX_ADDITIVE = 200;
    final int EX_THRESH = 30; 

    // Calculations

    int amountOver = (speedDriving - speedLimit);

    if (schoolZone.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        if (amountOver > 0)
            { int fine = amountOver * YES_MULTIPLIER + INIT_ADDITIVE;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
        if (amountOver > EX_THRESH)
            { int fine = amountOver * YES_MULTIPLIER + MAX_ADDITIVE;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
        else 
            { int fine = 0;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
    }

    if (schoolZone.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))  
    {

        if (amountOver > 0)
            { int fine = amountOver * NO_MULTIPLIER + INIT_ADDITIVE;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
        if (amountOver > EX_THRESH)
            { int fine = amountOver * NO_MULTIPLIER + MAX_ADDITIVE;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
        else 
            { int fine = 0;
            System.out.println(driverName +"owes: $" + fine);
            }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is the problem

```
// Call calcTicket

calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);
```

You can't have code just hanging around in a class like this. Put it into a method - I think you'd like to have it in main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    //Declarations and Instantiations
{
    // Input Data
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter driver's name: ");
    String driverName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter driver's speed: ");
    int speedDriving = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter speed limit: ");
    int speedLimit = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Was driver in school zone? ");
    String schoolZone = scan.nextLine();

//} --this is not good here!

    // Call calcTicket

    calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);

   } //put here instead...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the method within a method (or constructor). Place the callback within the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    //Declarations and Instantiations
{
    // Input Data
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter driver's name: ");
    String driverName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter driver's speed: ");
    int speedDriving = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter speed limit: ");
    int speedLimit = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Was driver in school zone? ");
    String schoolZone = scan.nextLine();

 // Call calcTicket

    calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the formatting got twisted up when you cut and paste your code into the question, but clearly you need to pull the call to `calcTicket` into the body of `main`. something like this:

```
...
System.out.println("Was driver in school zone? ");
String schoolZone = scan.nextLine();

}

// Call calcTicket

calcTicket(String driverName, int speedDriving, int speedLimit, String schoolZone);
```

to something like this:

```
System.out.println("Was driver in school zone? ");
String schoolZone = scan.nextLine();

// Call calcTicket
calcTicket(driverName, speedDriving, speedLimit, schoolZone);
}
```

and be sure to remove the arg types from the call; they are not needed.